# Travis CI running only PHP 5.5+ Behat tests with parse error about short array syntax []

Tags: php, behat, travis-ci

I'm trying to get Travis CI to run my Behat acceptance tests.

I've used PHP 5.5 in development and at the moment I’m really not concerned about compatibility with previous PHP versions. I've used the short array `[]` syntax introduced with PHP 5.4 extensively throughout my application.

I'm only trying to run my tests on 5.5+ upwards, I’m getting a parse error:

> Parse: syntax error, unexpected '['

If I echo `$TRAVIS_PHP_VERSION` I’m getting '5.5'.

My `travis.yml` looks like this:

```
language: php

php:
  - 5.5

before_script:

  - sudo apt-get install nginx
  - sudo apt-get install php5-fpm
  - sudo apt-get install php5-cli

  - sudo cp $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/vhost.template /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/fridge-subscription-demo.local
  - sudo sed 's|APP_URLS|fridge-subscription-demo.local|g;s|APP_PATH|/home/travis/build/EddyLane/DemoSubscriptionBundle|g;s|APP_NAME|fridge-subscription-demo.local|g' /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/fridge-subscription-demo.local --in-place

  - composer update
  - app/console doc:database:create
  - app/console doc:schema:update --force
  - app/console cache:warm

  - sudo chmod -R 0777 $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/app/cache
  - sudo chmod -R 0777 $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/app/logs

  - sudo service nginx restart
  - sudo service php5-fpm restart

  - echo $TRAVIS_PHP_VERSION

script:
  - ./bin/behat --config behat.yml

addons:
  hosts:
    - fridge-subscription-demo.local
```

The vhost is installed correctly, behat seems fine, it just keeps failing when it hits the short array syntax.

This project is open source and available here:      https://github.com/EddyLane/DemoSubscriptionBundle (currently attempting to get Travis to work on branch `travis`).

Comment: Welcome! Usually we try to avoid thank taglines in the questions to keep them tidier, you can read why in here: "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)".

Comment: It seems to be working for you now. https://travis-ci.org/EddyLane/DemoSubscriptionBundle/builds/17659605

Answer (score 0):

I also get this error because... It's because apt-get install adds PHP 5.3 packages that override actual PHP version.

Delete `apt-get install ...` and things should work. If you can't do it, then you have the same problem as me :-)

Good luck